# Stream Analytics Query working but no output to table

Tags: azure, azure-stream-analytics

I got a problem with my Stream Analytics job. I'm pulling events from an IoT Hub and grouping them in timewindows based on their custom timestamps; I've already written a query that does this correctly. But the problem is that it just doesn't write anything into my output table (being a NoSQL table on my Storage Account).

The query runs without problems in the query editor (when testing with a sample input file) and produces the correct output, but when running 'for real', it doesn't output anything (the output table remains empty). I've even tried renaming the table and outputting to a blob storage, but no dice. Here's the query:

```sql
SELECT
    'general' AS partitionKey, 
    MIN(ID_frame) AS rowKey, 
    DATEADD(second, 1, DATEADD(hour, -3, System.TimeStamp)) AS window_start, 
    System.TimeStamp AS window_end, 
    COUNT(ID_frame) AS device_count
INTO
    [IoT-Hub-output-table]
FROM
    [IoT-Hub-input] TIMESTAMP BY custom_timestamp
GROUP BY TumblingWindow(Duration(hour, 3), Offset(second, -1))
```

The interesting part is that, if I omit any windowing in my query, then the table output works just fine. 
I've been beating my head against the wall about this for a few days now, so I think I've already tried most of the obvious things.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the query **did** output into my table, but with an amount of delay I didn't expect; I was waiting for 20-30 minutes at max. while the first insertions would began after a little later than half an hour. Thus I was cancelling the Analytics job before any output was produced and falsely assuming it just wouldn't output anything.

I found this to be the case afer I noted that 'sometimes' (when the job was running for long enough) there appeared to be some output. And in those output records I noticed the big delay between my custom timestamp field and the general timestamp field (which the engine uses to remember when the entity was updated for the last time)

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a TumblingWindow of 3 hours, it means you will get a single output every 3 hours which contains an aggregate of all the events within that period.

So did you already wait for 3 hours for the first output to be generated?

I would try and set the window smaller, and try again to see if the output works correctly.

Comment: Then why do I get an immediate result when testing it in the query editor? BTW, initially I was testing this query with much smaller windows (like 5 - 30 secs), however, like with the bigger window version, it gave the correct output in the query tester but wouldn't write anything to the table once it was truly running